# grayscale bitmap into 2d array

Tags: java, image, image-processing, bufferedimage, bmp

Hi everyone i have problems in converting GrayScale bmp images into integer 2D-array (with values 0-255) in Java.

I have a pmb image that could be seen as an integer(0-255) 2D-array and i want to see that 2D-array in a Java data structure

i tried this way:

```
Image image = ImageIO.read(new File("my_img.bmp"));
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
Graphics g = img.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
g.dispose();
```

Then with my BufferedImage i create int[][] this way:

```
int w = img.getWidth();
int h = img.getHeight();

int[][] array = new int[w][h];
for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < h; k++) {
        array[j][k] = img.getRGB(j, k);
    }
}
```

But now all the 2D-array is full of number like "-9211021" or similar.

i think that the problem is in getRGB(j,k) but i don't know if it's possible to solve it.

edit:

i know RGB is not grayscale, so how can i get the grayscale value of a single pixel from a grayscale BufferedImage?

Comment: RGB is not greyscale, take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/PixelGrabber.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a grayscale image, *BufferedImage.getPixel(x,y)* wont give values within the [0-255] range. Instead, it returns the corresponding value of a gray level(intensity) in the RGB colorspace. That's why you are getting values like  *"-9211021"*.

The following snippet should solve your problem :

```
Raster raster = image.getData();
for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < h; k++) {
        array[j][k] = raster.getSample(j, k, 0);
    }
}
```

where *image* is the created BufferedImage. The 0 in the *getSample* indicates that we are accessing the first byte/band(setting it to a greater value will throw a *ArrayOutOfBoundException* in grayscale images).

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i solved in one other way, by extracting a single channer from the RGB value in this way: array[i][j] = (bmp.getRGB(i, j) >> 16) & 0xFF;

Comment: Then you used RED channel(>>16). If that suffices your need, it's okay. However, to obtain graylevel from RGB, usually all three channel values are extracted and converted as :
             I = .299 * R + .587 * G + .114 * B
only ~34% of the R value is considered for the intensity.